# Firebase Query and how to read the output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crud

[image]

Above is my Js code

I have a database that has information regarding the location of an apartment, I am trying to search for a specific property to see if it exists in the database. The user will be able to key into the search box to perform the search.

"propertiesRef" is used to store the user input.
I tried storing the data into "q" that I received from querying the database. But I have no idea how to read the result.

[image]

This is the console log for "q", but I don't quite understand the information that is shown, I want to know which output in the console should I be looking at and how do I access them?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

The [`query()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#query) function just creates an instance [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query.md#query_class). You need to use [`getDocs()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#getdocs) function to actually fetch data from Firestore.

```
const search = (property) => {
  const propertiesRef = collection(db, "flats-table");

  const q = query(propertiesRef, where("name", "==", property))

  return getDocs(q).then((qSnap) => {
    const data = qSnap.docs.map(d => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }))
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }) 

  // or use async-await
  // const qSnap = await getDocs(q);
}
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) for more examples.